# Replace item of QComboBox - pyside

Tags: python, pyside

I have a combobox where i add items in this way

```py
tmp_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
tmp_list2 = ['5', '6', '7', '8']
self.combobox = QComboBox()
self.combobox.addItem('First Item', tmp_list)
self.combobox.addItem('Second Item', tmp_list2)
```

Somewhere in my code `tmp_list` changes intentionally and I want to update the data.

```
tmp_list = ['8', '9', '7', '6']
```

How can i set the new list for `First Item` without losing `Second Item`.
I thought about using the `.removeItem()` function but how do I get the index of the item?
Knowing that there are not only 2 items

Comment: [`setItemData(index, data)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemData).

Comment: Thanks, it solve the problem! But just if I know when and which position I set the this item, what happen if I add it in different order, i mean: Find index of item which contain word 'second'

Comment: [`findText()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#findText). I strongly urge you to be more patient and always inspect the *whole* documentation of the classes you're using. Use search tools wisely: luckily enough, Qt has both good documentation and naming standards. It's a *huge* toolkit, with thousands of classes, each one having statistically 100+ functions on its own (at least), not mentioning *inherited* functions. Take your time, don't rush it. There's people that have been using it for *years* (me including) and even after that much experience they still find things they didn't know about.